# Separate website for different products in hosting

Tags: web, hosting, product, user-manual

I need some help with a project I am planning. I would like a website for customers where they can scan a qr code which takes them to a site with user manuals for their device. They should not necessarily have access to other user manuals if they do not have the correct qr code. The user manuals are preferrably pdf-files. Is the best solution to get a webserver and upload separate html files displaying separate pdfs in different folders, or are there any other smart solutions I have not yet heard of?

Appreciate all help!